# What does "$f''(x)$ exists" mean?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f$ is defined in a neighborhood of x, and suppose $f''(x)$ exists.
In this situation, I know $f'$ is continuous at x, but does $f'(x)$ exist near x?

Comment: $f''(x)$ is defined only when $f'$ exists in some open interval containing $x$.

Comment: In general, for a function $g(x)$ to have a derivative at a point $x_0$, one of the **necessary but not sufficient** conditions is that $g(x)$ be continuous at $x_0$.  
Therefore, $f'$ must not only exist but also be continuous at $x_0$ for $f''$ to exist at $x_0$.  I am unfamiliar with Kava Rama Murthy's additional requirement,  but my **blind guess** is that he knows what he's talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $f''(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}$, the existence of $f''(x)$ should imply the existence of $f'$ in a neighborhood of $x$ in order to make sense $f'(x+h)$ for $|h|$ small enough.

Answer (score 1):

It means that for any $x$ the following limit exists

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f'(x+h)-f'(x)}{h}$$

which requires that $f'(x)$ also exists.

Answer (score 1):

Since the second derivative of the function $f$ is defined as:
$$f''(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(f'(x)),$$
it's obvious that if $f''(x)$ exists in some open interval, then $f'(x)$ must exist too in that open interval.